# Google Guice module that loads two kinds of views

Tags: java, dependency-injection, javafx, dynamic-loading, guice

The code of my Guice Module looks like this:

```
public class FXMLModule extends AbstractModule {

    private final Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    private final ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n.messages", locale);

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Controller.class).annotatedWith(MainView.class).to(MainController.class);
        bind(Controller.class).annotatedWith(MovieView.class).to(MovieViewController.class);
    }

    @Provides @MainView
    public FXMLLoader mainViewLoader(@MainView Controller controller) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(locate("/jfx/fxml/MainView.fxml"), messages);
        loader.setController(controller);
        return loader;
    }

    @Provides @MovieView
    public FXMLLoader movieViewLoader(@MovieView Controller controller) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(locate("/jfx/fxml/MovieView.fxml"), messages);
        loader.setController(controller);
        return loader;
    }

    private URL locate(String location) {
        return getClass().getResource(location);
    }

}
```

Basically I want to inject fully configured `FXMLLoader`s into some Controller classes, so that they can work with the root nodes returned from the loaders without having to know anything about other controllers. The `MainViewLoader` gets injected into the `Application` class, and the `MovieViewLoader` gets injected into `MainViewController`. It works, but I'd have to write a provide method (with almost the same code) for every loader/controller. Any ideas how to make this more generic?

Answer (score 1):

What this is looking for is "Binding by Convention". Since Guice is intended to be as lightweight (and fast) as possible, it does **not** contain facilities to enable binding by convention.

Neither does Spring for that matter. I *think* you might be able to automate the bindings injected into the methods if you use [Plexus](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/plexus-containers/dependency-management.html).
Do note that none of this will alleviate you from the actual problem you're facing:

#### Why?

You write:

> Basically I want to inject fully configured FXMLLoaders into some
> Controller classes, so that they can work with the root nodes returned
> from the loaders without having to know anything about other
> controllers.

This makes  no sense: You're injecting `FXMLLoader`s into `Controller`s, specifically into a controller that's not the `Controller` you set on the `FXMLLoader` itself. To access the rootNode returned by the loader.

This violates the Law of Demeter. You're grabbing into the responsibilities of another controller.

The solution to this problem is to expose a method on the controller and inject a the controller instance you need, instead of the loader.

This whole module seems to me like it's solving the wrong problem in the first place ...